# Fit a GARCH (1,1) - model with covariates in R

Tags: r, regression, garch

I have some experiences with time series modelling, in the form of simple ARIMA models and so on. Now I have some data that exhibits volatility clustering, and I would like to try to start with fitting a GARCH (1,1) model on the data.

I have a data series and a number of variables I think influence it. So in basic regression terms, it looks like:

$$
y_t = \alpha + \beta_1 x_{t1} + \beta_2 x_{t2} + \epsilon_t .
$$

But I am at a complete loss at how to implement this into a GARCH (1,1) - model? I've looked at the `rugarch`-package and the `fGarch`-package in `R`, but I haven't been able to do anything meaningful besides the examples one can find on the internet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example of implementation using the `rugarch` package and with to some fake data. The function `ugarchfit` allows for the inclusion of external regressors in the mean equation (note the use of `external.regressors` in `fit.spec` in the code below).

To fix notations, the model is
\begin{align*}
y_t        &= \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 x_{t,1} + \lambda_2 x_{t,2} + \epsilon_t, \\
\epsilon_t &= \sigma_t Z_t , \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha \epsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta \sigma_{t-1}^2 ,
\end{align*}
where $x_{t,1}$ and $x_{t,2}$ denote the covariate at time $t$,
and
with the "usual" assumptions/requirements on parameters and the innovation process $Z_t$.

The parameter values used in the example are as follows.

```
## Model parameters
nb.period  <- 1000
omega      <- 0.00001
alpha      <- 0.12
beta       <- 0.87
lambda     <- c(0.001, 0.4, 0.2)
```

The image below shows the series of covariate $x_{t,1}$ and $x_{t,2}$ as well as the series $y_t$. The `R` code used to generate them is provided below.

[image]

```
## Dependencies
library(rugarch)

## Generate some covariates
set.seed(234)
ext.reg.1 <- 0.01 * (sin(2*pi*(1:nb.period)/nb.period))/2 + rnorm(nb.period, 0, 0.0001)
ext.reg.2 <- 0.05 * (sin(6*pi*(1:nb.period)/nb.period))/2 + rnorm(nb.period, 0, 0.001)
ext.reg   <- cbind(ext.reg.1, ext.reg.2)

## Generate some GARCH innovations
sim.spec    <- ugarchspec(variance.model     = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                          mean.model         = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = FALSE),
                          distribution.model = "norm", 
                          fixed.pars         = list(omega = omega, alpha1 = alpha, beta1 = beta))
path.sgarch <- ugarchpath(sim.spec, n.sim = nb.period, n.start = 1)
epsilon     <- as.vector(fitted(path.sgarch))

## Create the time series
y <- lambda[1] + lambda[2] * ext.reg[, 1] + lambda[3] * ext.reg[, 2] + epsilon

## Data visualization
par(mfrow = c(3,1))
plot(ext.reg[, 1], type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Covariate 1")
plot(ext.reg[, 2], type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Covariate 2")
plot(y, type = "h", xlab = "Time")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

A fit is done with `ugarchfit` as follows.

```
## Fit
fit.spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model     = list(model = "sGARCH",
                                                 garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                       mean.model         = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0),
                                                 include.mean = TRUE,
                                                 external.regressors = ext.reg), 
                       distribution.model = "norm")
fit      <- ugarchfit(data = y, spec = fit.spec)
```

Parameter estimates are

```
## Results review
fit.val     <- coef(fit)
fit.sd      <- diag(vcov(fit))
true.val    <- c(lambda, omega, alpha, beta)
fit.conf.lb <- fit.val + qnorm(0.025) * fit.sd
fit.conf.ub <- fit.val + qnorm(0.975) * fit.sd
> print(fit.val)
#     mu       mxreg1       mxreg2        omega       alpha1        beta1 
#1.724885e-03 3.942020e-01 7.342743e-02 1.451739e-05 1.022208e-01 8.769060e-01 
> print(fit.sd)
#[1] 4.635344e-07 3.255819e-02 1.504019e-03 1.195897e-10 8.312088e-04 3.375684e-04
```

And corresponding true values are

```
> print(true.val)
#[1] 0.00100 0.40000 0.20000 0.00001 0.12000 0.87000
```

The following figure shows a parameter estimates with 95% confidence intervals, and the true values. The `R` code used to generate it is provided is below.

[image]

```
plot(c(lambda, omega, alpha, beta), pch = 1, col = "red",
     ylim = range(c(fit.conf.lb, fit.conf.ub, true.val)),
     xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
box(); axis(1, at = 1:length(fit.val), labels = names(fit.val)); axis(2)
points(coef(fit), col = "blue", pch = 4)
for (i in 1:length(fit.val)) {
    lines(c(i,i), c(fit.conf.lb[i], fit.conf.ub[i]))
}
legend( "topleft", legend = c("true value", "estimate", "confidence interval"),
        col = c("red", "blue", 1), pch = c(1, 4, NA), lty = c(NA, NA, 1), inset = 0.01)
```

Comment: how did you estimate parameters( lambda,omega,alpha,beta)??

Comment: @chs The parameter estimates were obtained with the `ugarchfit` function.

Comment: is there a similar guide for the fgarch package?